# How to apply the Office 365 file handler extensions techniques to "OWA"?

Tags: office365, office365-apps

When I saw the page of the "Overview of Office365 file handlers"(*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/using-cross-suite-apps*), 
I can enable the following user experiences for non-Microsoft file types on "SharePoint Online" and "One Drive for Business":

1. customized file icons
2. file preview in the browser
3. rich view/edit capability

While these information is very great, I would like to apply these techniques to "OWA" too.
What would be a good way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

During Ignite 2015, [I demoed file handlers in Outlook Web App (OWA)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK4114) as something we are actively (and still) working on. Our team is currently validating that these add-ins work end to end in OWA, and will release the feature to the public after we finish this testing. We'll be sure to announce on Twitter, dev.office.com, etc. once we do - keep an eye out :)

Comment: Hi Dorren, where can I get more up-to-date tutorial? I checked your demo session, but Azure, Office 365 Admin, OneDrive etc all changed their user interfaces recently, so I'm kind of confused.